# Was a new constructor added to std::string in c++23 that accepts std::array<char, N>?

Tags: c++, c++23

Recently a bug was discovered in our code where we were accidentally converting a `std::array<char, N>` to `std::string`. The buggy code doesn't compile in c++20 mode but compiles and //mostly// works in c++23 mode except for some edge cases with null termination. I'm using gcc 11.1.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 3> x = {'a', 'b', '\0'};
    std::string s(x);
    std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << " has length " << s.size() << std::endl;
    //outputs "'ab' has length 3"
}
```

I suspect this may be related to [P1989R2 - Range constructor for std::basic_string_view](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1989r2.pdf) but I don't know what to make of it.

Is it a bug or just a weird behavior or what?

Comment: Looking closer it seems like this doesn't compile in gcc 12 nor in clang 15, so maybe it's a known bug that was squashed.

Comment: Compiles with GCC12 [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5fs7oT7Tz).  Pretty sure you are correct about the range constructor being used as an array is a range, and in C++17 std::string got an added constructor of `template< class StringViewLike > explicit basic_string( const StringViewLike& t, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is related to P1989.

One of `std::string`'s [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) is:

```cpp
template< class StringViewLike >
explicit constexpr basic_string( const StringViewLike& t,
                                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which is constrained on `StringViewLike` being convertible to `std::string_view`.

P1989 added this constructor to `std::string_view`:

```cpp
template <class R> requires /* ... */
constexpr string_view(R&&);
```

The constraints there require `R` to be a `contiguous_range` with appropriate value type and a few other things. Importantly, `std::array<char, N>` meets those requirements, and this constructor is not `explicit`.

As a result, you can now construct a `std::string` from a `std::array<char, N>`.

This led to [P2499](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2499r0.html) (`string_view` range constructor should be `explicit`), which suggested what the title says, and [P2516](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2516r0.html) (`string_view` is implicitly convertible from what?), which suggested removing the constructor entirely. In the end, the decision was to make [the constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) `explicit` rather than removing it entirely (or keeping it implicit):

```cpp
template< class R >
explicit constexpr basic_string_view( R&& r );
```

Because the `string` constructor from `StringViewLike` is constrained on *convertible to* (which requires implicit construction), this means `std::string` is no longer constructible from `std::array<char, N>` (or `std::vector<char>` or ... ).

Comment: So I guess string_view will still be constructable from array? that seems less bad but still problematic. Thanks for the quick and helpful answer.

Comment: @GranBurguesa Explicitly, yes. And constructing from a `std::array<char, 3>{'a', 'b', '\0'}` would give you a `std::string_view` whose length is 3, not 2.